# Need help analyzing slow boot (ASUS ROG X99, ACPI)

Tags: 17.04, asus, 17.10, acpi, boot-time

I have a fairly high end computer (8-core i7-6900K, Samsung SM961 1TB NVMe, 32GB RAM), but I have a very slow boot.

```
$ systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 21.766s (firmware) + 5.769s (loader) + 16.878s (kernel) + 3.532s (userspace) = 47.947s
```

I'm ignoring the firmware and loader for the time being. The userspace part takes less than four seconds, which is OK, but the **kernel is taking 17 seconds**!

I have boot information here:

- [boot-plot.svg](http://misc.bitsnbites.eu/boot-20171015/boot-plot.svg)
- [dmesg](https://paste.ubuntu.com/25744978/)

I have another similarly configured machine with another motherboard/chipset that is much faster at booting, so I suspect that the problem is with the chipset/HW, but I can not figure out what it is.

**UPDATE 1**: I have upgraded to Ubuntu 17.10, but the boot time is pretty much the same. Userspace is down to 2s (impressive!), but the kernel time is over 15s.

What I have noticed in the dmesg log is that there are a couple of time "jumps" around some ACPI messages:

```
[    0.166049] acpi PNP0A03:03: _OSC: OS supports [ExtendedConfig ASPM ClockPM Segments MSI]
[    2.208064] acpi PNP0A03:03: _OSC: platform does not support [PCIeHotplug]
[    4.256069] acpi PNP0A03:03: _OSC: OS now controls [PME AER PCIeCapability]
[    4.256070] acpi PNP0A03:03: FADT indicates ASPM is unsupported, using BIOS configuration
```

...and:

```
[    4.262024] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: OS supports [ExtendedConfig ASPM ClockPM Segments MSI]
[    6.304065] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: platform does not support [PCIeHotplug]
[    8.352073] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: OS now controls [PME AER PCIeCapability]
[    8.352074] acpi PNP0A08:00: FADT indicates ASPM is unsupported, using BIOS configuration
```

Is ACPI configuration having something to do with the slow kernel boot time?

**UPDATE 2**: Adding `acpi=off` to the boot parameters the kernel time is reduced from 15s to 7s (of which ~4s seems to be releated to mounting EXT4-fs on my nvme drive), so ACPI is definitely a time thief (~8s).

However, I do not wish to turn off ACPI completely. Is there some other ACPI-related configuration I can try?

Answer (score 0):

Same issue on X299 so lets have an answer after 6 years :) https://xkcd.com/979/

The slow boot is caused by some intentional delays implemented in firmware in DSDT. Every _OSC call is delayed with 1-2 seconds.

```
            Method (_OSC, 4, NotSerialized)  // _OSC: Operating System Capabilities
            {
                CreateDWordField (Arg3, 0x00, CDW1)
                If ((Arg0 == ToUUID ("33db4d5b-1ff7-401c-9657-7441c03dd766") /* PCI Host Bridge Device */))
                {
                    CreateDWordField (Arg3, 0x04, CDW2)
                    If ((Arg2 > 0x02))
                    {
                        CreateDWordField (Arg3, 0x08, CDW3)
                    }

                    SUPP = CDW2 /* \_SB_.PC00._OSC.CDW2 */
                    CTRL = CDW3 /* \_SB_.PC00._OSC.CDW3 */
                    If ((AHPE || ((SUPP & 0x16) != 0x16)))
                    {
                        CTRL &= 0x1E
                        Sleep (0x03E8)
                    }

                    If ((TBSE != 0x00))
                    {
                        CTRL &= 0x1E
                        Sleep (0x03E8)
                    }
```

The solution is to reduce the delays:

- Extract the DSDT:

  - `sudo cat /sys/firmware/acpi/tables/DSDT > dsdt.aml`
- Decompile and analize the file to adapt the subsequent commands:

  - `iasl dsdt.aml`
- Replace `Sleep (0x03E8)` (1s) `[\x5B\x22\x0B\xE8\x03]` with `Sleep (0x0064)` (100ms) `[\x5B\x22\x0B\x64\x00]`:

  - `perl -pe 's#\x5B\x22\x0B\xE8\x03#\x5B\x22\x0B\x64\x00#g' dsdt.aml > dsdt2.aml`
- Increase the DSDT revision to take precedence over built-in file. Replace `DefinitionBlock ("", "DSDT", 2, "ALASKA", "A M I ", 0x01072009)`
  with `DefinitionBlock ("", "DSDT", 2, "ALASKA", "A M I ", 0x01072010)`:

  - `perl -pe 's#\x09\x20\x07\x01#\x10\x20\x07\x01#g' dsdt2.aml > dsdt3.aml`
- Install the file:

  - `sudo cp dsdt3.aml /boot/dsdt.aml`
- Install `/etc/grub.d/01_acpi` from https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1045690

  - `chmod +x /etc/grub.d/01_acpi`
- Update grub:

  - `sudo update-grub`